# Using PKRevealController in one ViewController in Storyboard

Tags: ios, google-maps, storyboard, mapkit, viewcontroller

I have storyboards that contains 8-10 `ViewControllers` and each view controller is presented modally.

One of the view contains **Google Maps SDK for iOS**. On this view I need to use the [PKRevealController](https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController). This view is not the root view controller, and is presented to the user after going through some other views first.

How can I use PKRevealController on this view only, rather than having it throughout the application?